# Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition End of Statement Expected

Tags: vb.net

I have tried testing my web browser I have made by following a YouTube video. It doesn't work though. What is wrong with it?

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?g=") & (TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    WebBrowser1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where the error occurred, which makes it very hard to help you. But it looks like your problem is in this line:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?g=") & (TextBox2.Text)
```

This should be

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?g=" & TextBox2.Text)
```

As it is, you have an expression on a line by itself; the concatenation makes no sense.

---

In the future, please be sure to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I inboxed the YouTuber and they responded back. This is the correct code.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?g=" & TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    WebBrowser1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

End Class